# Meeting 'undefined reference to' errors when make SVM-map on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, undefined-reference

To do an LTR(Learning to Rank) mission, I want to build an LTR model, SVMmap, on Ubuntu 16.04. Then I just do the following things.

- download the source code from [Support Vector Machine for Optimizing Mean Average Precision](http://projects.yisongyue.com/svmmap/)
- activate the anaconda environment py27, which I config before and obviously the version of python is 2.7.
- just `make`

and then, it arises the following errors.

```
cd svm_light; make svm_learn_hideo_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/Research/TCP/Recognized/Tools/svm-map/svm_light'
gcc                           -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_learn_main.c -o svm_learn_main.o 
gcc                           -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_learn.c -o svm_learn.o 
svm_learn.c: In function ‘svm_learn_regression’:
svm_learn.c:508:10: warning: variable ‘r_delta_sq’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
double r_delta_sq=0,r_delta,r_delta_avg;
        ^
svm_learn.c:503:28: warning: variable ‘example_length’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
double loss,model_length,example_length;
                            ^
svm_learn.c: In function ‘svm_learn_optimization’:
svm_learn.c:902:10: warning: unused variable ‘r_delta_sq’ [-Wunused-variable]
double r_delta_sq=0,r_delta_avg;
        ^
svm_learn.c:897:28: warning: variable ‘example_length’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
double loss,model_length,example_length;
                            ^
svm_learn.c: In function ‘distribute_alpha_t_greedily’:
svm_learn.c:3897:8: warning: variable ‘best_depth’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
long best_depth=0;
        ^
gcc                           -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_common.c -o svm_common.o 
svm_common.c: In function ‘kernel’:
svm_common.c:71:5: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’ [-Wparentheses]
if(kernel_parm->kernel_type == GRAM)   /* use value from explicitly */
    ^
svm_common.c: In function ‘add_list_ns’:
svm_common.c:354:21: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
    long totwords,i,j;
                    ^
svm_common.c: In function ‘parse_document’:
svm_common.c:1162:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read_word’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
while((pos+=read_word(line+pos,featurepair)) &&
            ^
svm_common.c:1124:7: warning: unused variable ‘numread’ [-Wunused-variable]
int numread;
    ^
svm_common.c: In function ‘read_model’:
svm_common.c:953:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"SVM-light Version %s\n",version_buffer);
^
svm_common.c:958:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.kernel_type);  
^
svm_common.c:959:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.poly_degree);
^
svm_common.c:960:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.rbf_gamma);
^
svm_common.c:961:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.coef_lin);
^
svm_common.c:962:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->kernel_parm.coef_const);
^
svm_common.c:963:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%[^#]%*[^\n]\n", model->kernel_parm.custom);
^
svm_common.c:965:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->totwords);
^
svm_common.c:966:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->totdoc);
^
svm_common.c:967:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%ld%*[^\n]\n", &model->sv_num);
^
svm_common.c:968:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(modelfl,"%lf%*[^\n]\n", &model->b);
^
svm_common.c:976:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    fgets(line,(int)ll,modelfl);
    ^
gcc                           -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_hideo.c -o svm_hideo.o 
svm_hideo.c: In function ‘optimize_hildreth_despo’:
svm_hideo.c:480:13: warning: ‘g0_b2’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        g0_b2+=start[i]*g[i*n+j];
            ^
svm_hideo.c:459:13: warning: ‘g0_b1’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        g0_b1+=start[i]*g[i*n+j];
            ^
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/Research/TCP/Recognized/Tools/svm-map/svm_light'
cd svm_struct; make svm_struct_noexe
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/Research/TCP/Recognized/Tools/svm-map/svm_struct'
gcc -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_struct_learn.c -o svm_struct_learn.o
gcc -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_struct_classify.c -o svm_struct_classify.o
gcc -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_struct_common.c -o svm_struct_common.o
gcc -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  svm_struct_main.c -o svm_struct_main.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/Research/TCP/Recognized/Tools/svm-map/svm_struct'
gcc -c -lm -ldl -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  -I/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7  svm_struct_api.c -o svm_struct_api.o
In file included from /home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7/Python.h:80:0,
                from svm_struct_api.c:25:
svm_struct_api.c: In function ‘pythonObjectToSingleSV’:
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7/object.h:773:12: warning: ‘pTemp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        if (_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL  _Py_REF_DEBUG_COMMA       \
            ^
svm_struct_api.c:326:13: note: ‘pTemp’ was declared here
PyObject *pTemp, *py_words;
            ^
gcc -lm -ldl -O3 -Wall svm_light/svm_hideo.o svm_light/svm_learn.o svm_light/svm_common.o svm_struct_api.o svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_main.o -o svm_map_learn -Xlinker -export-dynamic -L/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil 
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
(.text+0x3aaa): warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
(.text+0x512): warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In function `classify_example':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x3f5): undefined reference to `tanh'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x46a): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x4d5): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In function `kernel':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x83b): undefined reference to `tanh'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x8a9): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x913): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In function `single_kernel':
svm_common.c:(.text+0xb29): undefined reference to `tanh'
svm_common.c:(.text+0xbd1): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
svm_common.c:(.text+0xc2e): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_divmod':
(.text+0x1670): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_pow':
(.text+0x2396): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_pow':
(.text+0x23de): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_pow':
(.text+0x24be): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_pow':
(.text+0x2537): undefined reference to `pow'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_rem':
(.text+0x26f0): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `_Py_double_round':
(.text+0x33ee): undefined reference to `round'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `_Py_double_round':
(.text+0x37d7): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(longobject.o): In function `PyLong_FromString':
(.text+0x7116): undefined reference to `log'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(signalmodule.o): In function `timeval_from_double':
(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to `floor'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(signalmodule.o): In function `timeval_from_double':
(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to `fmod'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x1582): undefined reference to `hypot'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x1593): undefined reference to `pow'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x15b2): undefined reference to `atan2'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x15e4): undefined reference to `sincos'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x1632): undefined reference to `exp'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
(.text+0x164b): undefined reference to `log'
/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_abs':
(.text+0x170c): undefined reference to `hypot'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'svm_map_learn_hideo' failed
make: *** [svm_map_learn_hideo] Error 1
```

I have searched some answers to this question, lots of answers told me to add `-lm` and '-ldl' as gcc arguments. However, it doesn't work.

How to fix it?

Comment: Add -lm and -ldl *at the end* of your gcc arguments. Actually I see that -ldl is already near the end of your gcc arguments, so just add -lm.

Comment: thanks, emmm... I have tried it. You can see the result in the question. each gcc is followed with `-c -lm -ldl ...`.

Comment: Try adding  -lm and -ldl  AT THE END OF YOUR COMMAND LINE AFTER ALL THE OTHER ARGUMENTS. Note to self, take a calm pill. What I'm trying to say is that the order matters. Add them AT THE END.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I do it and the commands are successfully changed to 
```gcc -c -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -lm -ldl svm_struct_learn.c -o svm_struct_learn.o```
```gcc -c -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -lm -ldl -I/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7  svm_struct_api.c -o svm_struct_api.o```@john
Still triggered this error

Comment: I made mistake. you mean AFTER ALL ARGUMENT and I just left it before .c files. You are right. when I change it to ```gcc -O3 -Wall svm_light/svm_hideo.o svm_light/svm_learn.o svm_light/svm_common.o svm_struct_api.o svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_main.o -o svm_map_learn -Xlinker -export-dynamic -L/home/parallels/Software/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil  -lm -ldl```
It build successful. The order indeed maters. Thank you.@john